# Identify a Spider-Man TV episode in which the villain was a speedster

Tags: story-identification, tv, spider-man, episode-identification, marvel

I remember watching a Spider-Man cartoon TV episode. The TV series was probably *Spectacular Spider-Man*, but I am not sure. Here are the details I remember:

- The villain was in some kind of exoskeleton using which he could run very fast.
- I don't remember what crimes he used to do, but it can be guessed Bank robbery.
- I remember Spider-Man chasing the villain after the crime and he always failed to catch him.
- Finally, in the end of the episode, Spider-Man guessed his route and jumped on him.
- To stop him, Spider-Man attached lots of spider webs between the villain's body/exoskeleton and neighboring buildings (just like he stopped the train in *Spider-Man 2* movie). It worked. It reduced his speed and probably knocked his helmet too.

I have already googled without any luck. Can you please identify that cartoon TV series and the episode?

**Update:**
Some features of the villain:

- His body part wasn't visible.
- His exoskeleton was 100% humanoid.
- His exoskeleton was white/silver.

**Update 2:**
I saw it before *Spider-Man 2* movie was released. It's because when I saw the train stopping scene in the movie, it looked familiar to me.

Comment: [Silvermane](http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/308/9/c/silvermane_by_spiedyfan-d835unp.png)?

Comment: [Speed Demon](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/SpiderManRoguesGallery)?

Comment: @Richard Speed Demon is red. Silvermane's face is visible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The episode is "[Heroes and Villains](http://marvelanimated.wikia.com/wiki/Episode:Heroes_and_Villains)" from *Spider-Man: The New Animated Series*

The villain is [Turbo Jet](http://marvelanimated.wikia.com/wiki/Turbo_Jet_(Spider-Man:_The_New_Animated_Series)), a former engineer working for NASA (possibly as a contractor at a high-tech firm) who developed a high-tech space suit that allowed the user to travel at high speeds, and use an unknown force to attract or repel objects. After being fired for stealing supplies, he continued work on his suit, stealing items at the bequest of a man in a nice suit (implied to be an associate of The Kingpin) to gain further funding, finally completing it, and deciding to use it to commit further crimes, both to acquire more money and to gain recognition for this theories, before eventually being defeated by Spider-Man who more or less overwhelmed him with webs before destroying his controls.

As you can see by the image below, the suit matches your description.

[image: Image of a sitting Turbo Jet with Spider-Man in the foreground]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your answer is effectively just a link at the moment - if the link ever breaks then it provides no detail. Can you please sum up the relevant information in the link as part of your answer.

Comment: Thanks *@Simpleton* and *@FuzzyBoots* for the edits. I now remember everything. That speedster even took Mary Jane with him in the end.